# Error: read ECONNRESET on native node.js http

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Having an issue. No modules except native `http` and `fs`:

```
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.on("clientError", err => {console.log(err.stack);});
    if (req.url == "/index.js") {
        fs.readFile("./index.js", (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.end(data);
        });
    } else {
        fs.readFile("./index.html", (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.end(data);
        });
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

On the first load, everything is served properly

On reload, it serves the HTML file and then throws that error.
my js file, which uses websocket connections, isn't served, so I don't think that that's the part of the code that's erroring

If you're interested in seeing the full code, you can find it [on my github](https://github.com/vityavv/connectFour/) (it's a connect four game)

Comment: In my opinion the server has been crash because your `wsServer` logic, you can try comment the block code  impliment ws and try refresh page too much -> it is ok.
I have a suggestion, you can add this line `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () { ws.close(); });` to your js client file (index.js)

Comment: I doubt that is the problem because when the problem occurs the JavaScript file doesn't even get served

Comment: Huh. I tried that and it seemed to fix it. Thanks, @hoangdv